Prioritize/Ranking based on CASE WHEN condition
I want to create a new column called "Priority" and in order to do so I have to look at multiple TABLE_ID's and within them are ACCOUNT_IDs that are assigned to the TABLE_ID. There can be duplicate TABLE_IDs but unique ACCOUNT_ID. Multiple ACCOUNT_IDs can be assigned to one TABLE_ID which is why I want to prioritize them. The issue I am having is that instead of prioritizing them I'm getting numbers beyond what I have assigned as row_number when I partition.
Here is an example of the table that I have:



TABLE_ID
ACCOUNT_ID
ACCOUNT_NAME




10101010
02020202
PREMIUM


10101010
02020204
PERFORMANCE


0120202
0930303
PERFORMANCE


0120202
039303
VALUE


0303303
039302929
VALUE


0303303
0393342929
PLUS



Here is the expected results:



TABLE_ID
ACCOUNT_ID
ACCOUNT_NAME
Priority




10101010
02020202
PREMIUM
1


10101010
02020204
PERFORMANCE
2


0120202
0930303
PERFORMANCE
1


0120202
039303
VALUE
2


0303303
039302929
VALUE
1


0303303
0393342929
PLUS
2



I basically want to prioritize the ACCOUNT_ID based on the ACCOUNT_NAME where:
PREMIUM = 1
PERFORMANCE = 2
VALUE = 3 
PLUS = 4 

However, if a TABLE_ID doesn't have an ACCOUNT_ID with a PREMIUM ACCOUNT_NAME then the priority should be assigned to the next which is PERFORMANCE which should be Priority = 1 as it's the first priority account when PREMIUM is absent. I am trying to achieve this using proc sql in sas and I keep getting priority numbers greater than what is set out in the case conditions.
SELECT 
    *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY TABLE_ID
        ORDER BY 
            CASE 
                WHEN ACCOUNT_NAME = 'PREMIUM' THEN 1 
                WHEN ACCOUNT_NAME  = 'PERFORMANCE' THEN 2
                WHEN ACCOUNT_NAME  = 'VALUE' THEN 3
                WHEN ACCOUNT_NAME  = 'PLUS' THEN 4
                ELSE 5
            END
    ) AS Priority
FROM 
   TABLE_A as a;



Your results don't make sense to me.  For TABlE_ID='0120202' you have two observations with ACCOUNT_NAME values of 'PERFORMANCE' and 'VALUE '.  From your priority mapping they should map to priorities of 2 and 3.  Why do you show 1 and 2 in your expected results?  Do you want to take the MIN() or 2 and 3?  Or the MAX()?  Why are adding the complication of using SQL windowing functions?  Those will not work in PROC SQL, but I don't see why you would need them anyway.

Because what I want is if there is no PREMIUM as in the case with 0120202 then priority 1 should go to PERFORMANCE and 2 should go to VALUE.

So what you are calling PRIORITY is really just an ORDER or a RANK?

Given that the case statement is only setting the ORDER criteria it is not surprising that you could get row_number() values that are larger than 5.  That would happen for any TABLE_ID with more than 5 observations.

Sort the data. Then you can and count/order/rank the observations.
First let's convert your listing into an actual dataset we can program from:
data have;
  input TABLE_ID $ ACCOUNT_ID :$10. ACCOUNT_NAME :$20.;
cards;
0120202  0930303    PERFORMANCE
0120202  039303     VALUE
0303303  039302929  VALUE
0303303  0393342929 PLUS
10101010 02020202   PREMIUM
10101010 02020204   PERFORMANCE
;

You could use CASE statement in PROC SQL to map ACCOUNT_NAME into an numeric value so you can use it for ordering.  (or you could create an informat and use the INPUT() function.)  Then order the data by that numeric variable.  Once it is ordered you can then count the observations.
proc sql ;
create table STEP1 as 
select *
     ,case when ACCOUNT_NAME = 'PREMIUM' then 1
           when ACCOUNT_NAME = 'PERFORMANCE' then 2
           when ACCOUNT_NAME = 'VALUE' then 3
           when ACCOUNT_NAME = 'PLUS' then 4
           else 99
      end as ACCOUNT_PRIORITY
from have
order by TABLE_ID, ACCOUNT_PRIORITY, ACCOUNT_NAME
;
quit;

data want;
  set step1;
  by table_id account_priority;
  priority+1;
  if first.table_id then priority=1;
run;

